# concise function definition that only return parameter value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to enable users of my class to define a transformation function, that is applied multiple times within the class. If this transformation is not defined, the value should just stay the same.

This is my (probably way to verbose) solution right now:

```
def do_nothing(val):
    return val

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, transformation_function = None):
        if transformation_function is None:
            self.transform = do_nothing
        else:
            self.transform = transformation_function
```

How can I write this more concise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
self.transform = transformation_function or lambda x: x
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `do_nothing` as a default value:

```
def do_nothing(val):
    return val

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, transformation_function=do_nothing):
        self.transform = transformation_function
```